# I want to add check sign in row when any row is selected in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want to add a check sign when any row is selected in table view please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in your table view delegate, grab the cell that was selected using `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` and set its accessory to `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`.

If you want to implement something similar to the multi-value table views in the Settings app, what I do is use a property to keep track of what's already selected:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
```

In the same delegate method, I remove the checkmark from the cell at the selection, add the checkmark to the cell that was tapped and update the property with the index of that cell:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath];
    [oldCell setAccessory:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

    UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [newCell setAccessory:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

    [self setSelectedIndexPath:indexPath];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

To go one step further, you can find a way to persist the index path in your app (possibly using `NSUserDefaults`, and in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` apply the checkmark to whichever cell that corresponds to that index path, so your checkmark shows up on view load.

Comment: Problem is that this select more than one but i want to put check on only one row

Answer (score 3):

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/table-view-multi-row-edit-mode.html